# How to concat LPCWSTR and char[]?

Tags: c++, string, char, concatenation

I am trying to concat a LPCWSTR and a char[] (and get LPCWSTR as output).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your `char[]` array into a wide-char array using the following code (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235631.aspx))

```
wchar_t * wcstring = new wchar_t[strlen(array) + 1];

// Convert char* string to a wchar_t* string.
size_t convertedChars = 0;
mbstowcs_s(&convertedChars, wcstring, strlen(array) + 1, array, _TRUNCATE);
```

After that you can use `wcscat_s` to concatenate the converted character array to your original `LPCWSTR`.

Comment: I tried that but I get : "error C2664: 'errno_t wcscat_s(wchar_t *,rsize_t,const wchar_t *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCWSTR' to 'wchar_t *'"

Comment: You would have to use the original LPCWSTR as the 3rd parameter. So the call would look like wcscat_s(wcstring, strlen(array) + 1, /* LPCWSTR */). If you want the concatenation like LPCWSTR+char[] you have to copy the LPCWSTR into the wide char array first.

Comment: use LPWSTR , it is wchar_t*. LPCWSTR is const wchar_t*. So you may return LPWSTR as LPCWSTR, it would be automatically casted

Comment: It works, but it's not the most efficient way: create a buffer big enough for the result, copy the wide input string first, and have `mbstowcs` write directly to that buffer. This saves the unnecessary copy of `wcscat`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying o concatenate a UNICODE string with an ANSI string. This won't work unless you convert the ANSI string to UNICODE. You can use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx) for that, or [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you're using ATL or MFC.

Comment: what about converting the char[] to a LPCWSTR? Wouldn't that be easier? MultiByteToWideChar has too many arg I don't know what they mean :P

Comment: @riviraz: What is the maximum number of arguments you can accept? Try `mbstowcs()` if you don't need the options `MultiByteToWideChar()` provides.

Comment: I've tried mbstowcs already but I get "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'LPCWSTR' to 'wchar_t *'"

Comment: @riviraz: use `mbstowcs()` for multibyte -> widechar. You're probably using it the other way around. You can also try `wcstombs()`.